# Send Email With Multiple RangeToHTML Ranges

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am using some code copied from Ron de Bruin's website (awesome, btw) and am running into a snag.

The email that's generated will paste only the header to the `completedTasks` range.

It will correctly paste the `Summary` and `incompletedTasks` ranges to the body of the email.

If I remove all code dealing with `incompletedTasks` then it will correctly paste the `Summary` and `completedTasks` HTML to the email body.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function


Sub Monthly_Close_Daily_Report()
'
'

Dim yearMonth As String
Dim closeDay As String
Dim currTime As String
Dim summaryRange As Range
Dim completedTasks As Range
Dim incompleteTasks As Range
Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
Dim sTo As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Inputs").Select

'Check to make sure there are no errors, then proceed
If Not IsError(Sheets("Inputs").Range("B12")) Then
    If Sheets("Inputs").Range("B12") = "Yes" Then
        'Store the YY-MM as a variable
        Sheets("Inputs").Select
        yearMonth = Range("B4").Value

        'Store the MM/DD/YYYY as a variable
        Sheets("Inputs").Select
        closeDay = Range("B5").Value

        'Store the current time as a variable
        Sheets("Inputs").Select
        currTime = Format(Now(), "h:mmAM/PM")

        'Unfilter the Task Listing tab
        Sheets("Task Listing").Select
        Activesheet.ShowAllData

        'Refresh the table with new Sharepoint data
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("SharePoint").Refresh

            'Create a new email with the Email Listing tab in the "To" line
            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            'Determine the email addresses to send to
            Set emailRng = Worksheets("Email Listing").Range("B2:B50")
            For Each cl In emailRng
                sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
            Next
            sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)

            'Set the Summary range to be copied into the email
            Set summaryRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("A1:G11")
            summaryRange.Copy

            'Filter the Task Listing tab for this month's completed tasks & copy to range
            Sheets("Task Listing").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Close_Tasks").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=yearMonth, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Close_Tasks").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1 _
                :="Completed"
            Set completedTasks = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), Range("A:G"))
            'Set completedTasks = Sheets("Task Listing").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            Worksheets("Task Listing").ShowAllData

            'Filter the Task Listing tab for this month's non-completed tasks & copy to range
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Close_Tasks").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=yearMonth, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Close_Tasks").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>Completed"
            Set incompleteTasks = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), Range("A:G"))

            'On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = sTo
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Month End Close Status for " & yearMonth & " As Of " & currTime & " on " & closeDay
                .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(summaryRange) & "<br><br><strong>Completed Tasks" & RangetoHTML(completedTasks) & "<br><br><strong>Incomplete Tasks" & RangetoHTML(incompleteTasks)
                .Display 'Can also use .Send which will send the email.  We want to preview before sending, though.
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
            Set OutApp = Nothing

    Else
        'If tasks are missing Due Dates, flag those for the user and exit the macro
        MsgBox ("There are ""Due Dates"" missing for some tasks.  Please correct the issue and run the macro again.")
    End If

End If

    'Filter the "Task Listing" tab for the current month
    Sheets("Task Listing").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Close_Tasks").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=yearMonth, Operator:=xlFilterValues

'

End Sub
```

Comment: my solution was to join all the ranges in a new worksheet and than send the entire rng (sheet) as one block

Comment: I thought of that, but it seems cumbersome to me, especially since I have several text headers for the ranges which I am manually adding in the body of the email.

Comment: copy paste and keep track of the last line for headers last line +=2 for range last line += range. rows. count. sorry for not remembering the right code

Comment: Can you share an example of your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved using the suggestion from @Asaf to use a "holding" sheet to combine the ranges and then pasting the HTML to email.

```
Sub Monthly_Close_Daily_Report()
'
'
Dim yearMonth As String
Dim closeDay As String
Dim currTime As String
Dim summaryRange As Range
Dim completedTasks As Range
Dim incompleteTasks As Range
Dim placeholderRange As Range
Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim sTo As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Inputs").Select

'Check to make sure there are no errors, then proceed
If Not IsError(Sheets("Inputs").Range("B12")) Then
    If Sheets("Inputs").Range("B12") = "Yes" Then
        'Store the YY-MM as a variable
        Sheets("Inputs").Select
        yearMonth = Range("B4").Value

        'Store the MM/DD/YYYY as a variable
        Sheets("Inputs").Select
        closeDay = Range("B5").Value

        'Store the current time as a variable
        Sheets("Inputs").Select
        currTime = Format(Now(), "h:mmAM/PM")

        'Unfilter the Task Listing tab
        Sheets("Task Listing").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter

        'Refresh the table with new Sharepoint data
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("SharePoint").Refresh

            'Create a new email with the Email Listing tab in the "To" line, and Alan and Tim cc'd
            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            'Determine the email addresses to send to
            Set emailRng = Worksheets("Email Listing").Range("B2:B50")
            For Each cl In emailRng
                sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
            Next
            sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)

            'Set the Summary range to be copied into the email
            Set summaryRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("A1:G11")
            summaryRange.Copy

            'Filter the table for "Completed" and then add it to the placeholder tab to be converted to HTML
            Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Placeholder"
            Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Completed Tasks"
            With Selection.Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .Size = 18
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            End With
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Sheets("Task Listing").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Close_Tasks").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=yearMonth, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Close_Tasks").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1 _
                :="Completed"
            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Placeholder").Select
            Range("A3").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'Find the last row of the "Placeholder" sheet
            lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            'Copy the format to the "Incomplete" section header
            Range("A1").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("A" & lastRow + 3).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Incomplete Tasks"

            'Filter the table for "Incomplete" and then add it to the placeholder tab to be converted to HTML
            Sheets("Task Listing").Select
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Close_Tasks").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1 _
                :="=In Progress", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Not Started"
            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Placeholder").Select

            'Find the new last row of the "Placeholder" tab
            lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            'Paste the incomplete tasks to the "Placeholder" tab
            Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'Format the "Placeholder" tab
            Cells.Select
            With Selection
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

            'Find the new last row of the "Placeholder" tab
            lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            'Make the entire "Placeholder" sheet the placeholderRange
            Set placeholderRange = Range("A1:G" & lastRow)

            'On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = sTo
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Month End Close Status for " & yearMonth & " As Of " & currTime & " on " & closeDay
                '.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(summaryRange) & "<br><br><strong>Completed Tasks" & RangetoHTML(completedTasks) & "<br><br><strong>Incomplete Tasks" & RangetoHTML(incompleteTasks)
                .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(summaryRange) & "<br><br>" & RangetoHTML(placeholderRange)
                .Display 'Can also use .Send which will send the email.  We want to preview before sending, though.
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
            Set OutApp = Nothing

    Else
        'If tasks are missing Due Dates, flag those for the user and exit the macro
        MsgBox ("There are ""Due Dates"" missing for some tasks.  Please correct the issue and run the macro again.")
    End If

End If

    'Delete the Placeholder tab
    Sheets("Placeholder").Delete

    'Filter the "Task Listing" tab for the current month
    Sheets("Task Listing").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Close_Tasks").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=yearMonth, Operator:=xlFilterValues

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're pulling both ranges from the same sheet, it's the same sheet only with filtering.

Set input to Completed
Set input to Incomplete

completed = RangetoHTML(input) //you're reading the incompletes
incomplete = RangetoHTML(input) //you're reading the incompletes again

Instead try this

Set input to Completed
htmlBodyBuffer = RangetoHTML(input)

Set input to Incomplete
.HTMLBody = htmlBodyBuffer & RangetoHTML(input)